# Trying to verify signature of Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb package but it won´t find the file (THE FILE IS THERE)

Tags: command-line, software-installation, downloads, gnupg, signature

Ey there,

So, i have been trying for hours to install wasabi in Ubuntu without success. Having downloaded the
files and following the guide i get to the point of not being able to verify the freaking signature.

I write the following command (taken from the installation guide i'm following at http://wasabiwallet.io):

```
gpg --verify Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb
```

and the terminal tells me there is no such file (but the files is there... i'm sure

The text i get back is:

> ```
> gpg: can´t open 'Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb.asc: No such file or directory
> gpg: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory
> ```

And so...  I'm lost. I googled but did not find anything helpful. I just spend a couple days to install the VPN (a couple weeks ago) and remember my ex flatmate who was a computer wizard and still was to be seen losing his hair with Ubuntu once in a while... and i wonder why i even try to use it XD.

I hope someone here can help me.

TO BE CLEAR:

-Followed the Guide's steps

1. .deb file downloaded
2. .deb.asc file downloaded in same folder
3. PGP.txt imported

I give `gpg --verify Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb.asc`
(yes, i checked, File name is correct)

I receive:

> ```
> gpg: can´t open 'Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb.asc: No such file or directory
> gpg: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but you did read step 2 at least twice, right?

[image: Step 2]

There is [the `.deb` file](https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/releases/download/v1.1.12.3/Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb) and, under the green button, a blue "Signature" link that points to [the `.asc` file](https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/releases/download/v1.1.12.3/Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb.asc). Both will need to be located in the same directory.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jason jason 69997812 12月  7 23:22 Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jason jason      499 12月  7 23:23 Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb.asc
```

Now you can then perform Step 3 and verify the `.deb`:

```
$ gpg --verify Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb.asc

gpg: assuming signed data in 'Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb'
gpg: Signature made 2020年12月07日 23時22分15秒 JST
gpg:                using RSA key 6FB3872B5D42292F59920797856348328949861E
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

So long as the RSA key matches what is listed on the website, you can move on to the next step.

Comment: Ey! Thanks for the answer.

As i said, the file is there. That is because i went and downloaded it as said in the step 2. I do have both files in the same folder. I did also import the PGP.txt.

So let me be clear so we all save some time:

.deb file downloaded
.deb.asc file downloaded in same folder

PGP.txt imported

I give gpg --verify Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb.asc

I receive "gpg: can´t open 'Wasabi-1.1.12.3.deb.asc: No such file or directory gpg: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory"

Thanks anyway and have a great day!

Comment: For the sake fo completeness, could you update your question to include the output of: (1) `gpg --version` and (2) `ll Wasabi*` (be sure to do this from the directory where the Wasabi files are). I wonder if this might be a file permissions or an outdated decryption library issue.

Comment: Yes!

$ gpg --version

gpg (gnuPG) 2.2.19

Libgcrypt 1.8.5

Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later

Supported algorithms:

Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA

Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CASTS, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH, CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256

Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224

Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2


$ 11 Wasabi*  gives me "11: command not found"

Comment: We're using the same version of `gpg`, then. As for the second command, that's two lower-case [L]'s 

Comment: Sorry... i m really an ubuntu ignorant. 

ll Wasabi*

"ls: cannot acces 'wasabi*': No such file or directory

Comment: It looks like you are not in the same directory as where you downloaded your files, which would explain why things are not working. *IF* you downloaded these files through a browser, then you will probably need to do this: (1) Open a Terminal (2) `cd ~/Downloads` (3) `ll Wasabi*`. If you downloaded the `.deb` and `.asc` file some other way, then I will not try to guess where they are on your computer 

Comment: I got it... like always... i have NO IDEA how. I just restarted everything, deleted the files, downloaded them again, run some lines i copied from a forum and PUM!

I got verified... I tried to install.. some fronlocked was locked (isnt that the point? XD ) and run some more lines from another forum and PUM! I´m stalling Wasabi

At this point Either i find a way to learn Linux or i throw the whole thing away and stick to Windows...

Comment: Oh... i was in the same directory

Could this have been all cuz of ortography... Wasabi vs Wassabi... or Downloads folder being actually downloads, etc?

Comment: どうもありがとうございました   <3<3<3